# Write a function that counts the number of individual words in a given string argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this problem im trying to solve but i'm having a hard time getting the output I want. This is what I have.

```
var stringLength = [];
function wordCount(text) {
      stringLength.push(text.split(' ').join(' , '))
      console.log(stringLength.length)
    }

wordCount('All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy');
```

This should return '10'. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: `This should return '10'` ... why? and what does it "return"?

Comment: Why is `stringLength` an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're splitting it up, but then you're joining them all back together....so `text.split(' ')` forms an array on individual words, but then the `.join(' , ')` joins all the words together into a single string (separated by commas)

It should just be:

```
function wordCount(text) {
    return text.split(' ').length
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to split on the spaces (`' '`), that will return an array of words that you can get the `length` property from:

```js
function wordCount(text) {
  return text.split(' ').length;
}

var count = wordCount('All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy'); //10
console.log(count);
```